# Duda comprobación while Pascal

Tags: pascal

Tengo un problema con Pascal. Estoy creando una base de datos de personas, con la función NUEVO de crear registro tiene que verificar que el nº de documento introducido no se encuentre ya en la base de datos.

El primer problema que me encuentro es que hace la verificación una vez cerrado el programa, pero no hace la comprobación mientras el programa está en ejecución y voy introduciendo registros.

El compilador usado es Lazarus V2.2.6.

Tipos de datos:

```
TRegistroPersona= packed record
 Id: int64;
 Nombre, Apellido: String[20];
 Documento: String[10];
 Edad, Peso: byte;
 Eliminado: boolean;
end;

TBaseDeDatos= file of TRegistroPersona;
```

Código:

```
    if  FileExists (BASEDEDATOS_NOMBRE_REAL) then begin
      reset (archivoDataBase);
      seek (archivoDataBase, FileSize (archivoDataBase));
    end else begin
    rewrite (archivoDataBase);
    end;

 {DENTRO DE CREAR REGISTRO, REALIZARMOS ESTA VERIFICACION}


 while not eof (archivoDataBase) do begin
         read (archivoDataBase,registroPersonaAux);
         prueba:=compareStr (objCom.listaParametros.argumentos[1].datoString, registroPersonaAux.Documento)=0;
         if prueba=true then begin
           writeln ('Ya existe este numero de documento');
           write (PROMPT);
           readln (entradaEstandar);
           ObjCom:=crearComando(entradaEstandar);
           sysCom:=comandoSistema(objCom);
         end;
  end;

seek (archivoDataBase, FileSize (archivoDataBase));
              write (archivoDataBase, registroPersona);
              writeln ('Registro agregado correctamente');

              registroPersona.Documento:='';
              registroPersona.Nombre:='';
              registroPersona.Apellido:='';
              registroPersona.Edad:=0;
              registroPersona.Peso:=0;

              CloseFile (archivoDataBase);
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda prestada.

Saludos.

Comment: Para poderte responder haría falta que agregues la definición del tipo de registro y que indiques el compilador que usas. Un saludo.

Comment: Aquí dejo los tipados:

  {Representa el registro de una persona en el sistema.}
  TRegistroPersona= packed record
     Id: int64;
     Nombre, Apellido: String[20];
     Documento: String[10];
     Edad, Peso: byte;
     Eliminado: boolean;
  end;

  {El archivo en el que se guardarán los datos.}
  TBaseDeDatos= file of TRegistroPersona; 

El compilador utililizado es Lazarus V2.2.6.

Muchas gracias